# Express router no recibe parámetros

Tags: express, router

estoy intentando hacer compatible mi sistema de express con mySQL para conectarme a una base de datos que está en funcionamiento cuando estaba trabajando con mongo todo funcionaba correctamente
ahora hago peticiones a través de post-man y recibo siempre el get('/' incluso cuando envíos parámetros get('/:id' no tengo idea de por que.
en mi archivo routes/eventos.js he escrito el siguente código.
antes de buscar los routers importo y utilizo, body-parser, morgan y cors que no salen en el còdigo

```
          const express = require("express");
      
          const router = express.Router();
              
          router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
              req.getConnection((error, con) => {
              const { id } = req.params.id;
              console.log(id)// este console. log devuelve undefined
              sql = `SELECT   * FROM events evt_id=${id}`;
              con.query(sql, (errorq, result) => {
                result
                  ? res.json(result)
                  : res.send("No hay resultados");
              });
            });
          });
          router.get("/", (req, res) => {
            req.getConnection((error, con) => {
              if (error) console.error(error);
              sql ="SELECT * FROM eventos";
              con.query(sql, (errorq, results) => {
                console.log(results)
                results 
                  ? res.json(results)
                  : res.sendStatus(204);
              });
            });
          });
      
          
      
          module.exports = router
```

y en el archivo app.js lo llamo de la siguiente manera

```
            const express = require('express')
            const mySQL = require('mysql')
            const myCon = require('express-myconnection')
            
            const eventos= require('./routes/eventos')
            const auth = require('./routes/auth')
    
            var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
            app.set('port', port);
    
            app.use(myCon(mySQL, 
                {
                    host: 'localhost',
                    user: 'user',
                    password: 'pass',
                    port: 3306,
                    database: 'name-bd',
                    dateStrings: true
                }, 'single'))      
            app.use('/api/auth', auth)       
            app.use('/api/eventos', eventos)
            module.exports = app
```

El problema es que cuando realizo una petición get con parámetros entra al get raíz
y en las peticiones put y delete no reciben los parámetros que están definidos en el router.
Por favor necesito ayuda!!!

Comment: Uno de los errores más comunes está en el orden en que declaras los *middlewares* para el proceso de las peticiones a las diferentes rutas. Con esto quiero decir que si declaras primero un *middleware* que maneje la ruta a `/`, cualquier otra ruta (por ejemplo `/test` o `/:id`) hará `match` con la ruta `/`, ejecutándose siempre el *middleware* declarado para `/`. Prueba cambiando el orden de declaración de los *middlewares*, de tal manera que primero tengas el *middleware* que maneja la ruta `/:id` y de último el *middleware* que maneja la ruta `/`. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero no funcionó :/

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en como enviaba el parametro, ya que express recibe parametros tipo Body, query o resource y yo le estaba mandando un parametro tipo query y recibiendo en mi código uno tipo resource.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).